# Why is my new view controller not appearing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am using the following code to push my view controller, except when the UIButton is pressed - nothing happens apart from the NSLog statement:

```
-(IBAction)doChangePasscode{

NSLog(@"Change Passcode Screen Loaded!"); 

ChangePasscode *cpscreen = [[ChangePasscode alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChangePasscode" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cpscreen animated:YES];

}
```

I have imported the relavant files (using #import) so everything should be fine...

Why is this happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Double check if  cpscreen and Self.navigationController are Not Nil.

Comment: Try to `NSLog` self.navigationController and check if it nil..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you debugged and checked that your `navigationController` isn't nil ?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController); and check if its nil or not.

Comment: Then check why its null :)
Have you initialized navigation controller correctly?

Comment: I haven't initialised any navigation controller, so how can I do this?

Comment: Added link in answer, hope it'll help you :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4672/discussion-between-reddexuk-and-aahsanali)

Comment: Please can we chat about it briefly? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must check first from which button click action you are push viewcontroller That viewcontroller must be embed in UINavigationcontroller, after that you will able to push viewcontroller from that Navigation viewcontroller.

**Your parent Viewcontroller must be embed in UINavigationviewcontroller.**