# What can I do if my navigationController returns "(null)"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't I push a new view controller onto the current view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986045/why-cant-i-push-a-new-view-controller-onto-the-current-view)
>   [Why is my new view controller not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986700/why-is-my-new-view-controller-not-appearing)

I need to push my view controller from my navigationController, but after having done an NSLog statement to find out why nothing was showing with the following code, I realised that it was returning null:

```
-(IBAction)doChangePasscode{

NSLog(@"Change Passcode Screen Loaded!"); 

ChangePasscode *cpscreen = [[ChangePasscode alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChangePasscode" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cpscreen animated:YES];

NSLog(@"%@",self.navigationController); 

}
```

Why is this happening? What can I do to return a proper value other than (null)?

Comment: What is the original controller you have this code in? Is it in fact a NavigationController?

Comment: Not sure, it's just called "ViewController.m"...

Comment: Can you show the code where you are initializing and displaying the  `self` view controller in the above code?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have your navigation controller properly hooked up to your view. Can you post some code? It's pretty hard for us to guess at this.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986700/why-is-my-new-view-controller-not-appearing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986045/why-cant-i-push-a-new-view-controller-onto-the-current-view Please stop posting new questions and follow up on the older ones !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like everyone has explained in this and *[Why is my new view controller not appearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986700/why-is-my-new-view-controller-not-appearing)*, you need to have a navigation controller first.  Use that nav controller to push your view controllers and then your view controllers will no longer have null for the `navigationController` property.

In this example `someSecondViewController` would be the `self` in your code above:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];
    [rootViewController release];
    [self.window addSubview:nav.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    SecondViewController *someSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.nav pushViewController:someSecondViewController animated:YES];
    [someSecondViewController release];
}
```

Please review these:

[View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457)
[UINavigationController Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[UIViewController Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean returning nil, that means the viewController does not have a navigation controller, you can solve it by having your viewController be the root of a newly created UINavigationController like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myRootViewController];
```

Then for myRootViewController self.navigationController will return the navigation Controller.

I am assuming that viewController is the first one in your app so you want to have this on your appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MyViewController *viewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    UINavigationController *myNavController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];

    self.window.rootViewController = myNavController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Then if that IBAction is on MyViewController self.navigationController will return the navigation Controller instead of nil.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What do I put where you say "myRootViewController"?

Comment: The viewController instance you want to be the first viewController on the navigation Controller stack.

Comment: I put "ViewController" but it came up with an error and said that it is an undeclared identifier :(